# Как в vue router обработать запрос в middleware?

Tags: nuxt.js, vue-router, ssr, middleware

Используется: Nuxt, Expressjs.

Режим SSR.

При открытии страницы мне нужно получать данные req\res. В частности, `res.getHeader('Content-Length')`

При открытии страницы в браузере эти данные получить легко, однако, если мы перешли по ссылке роутера (nuxtlink), то в мидлваре вообще нет ничего.

Я пробовал:

- на стороне сервера перед app.use(nuxt.render) использовать свою мидлварю и там в 
  `res.on('finish',...)` получать данные - ничего не срабатывает.
- на стороне middleware (`router: { middleware: ['mymiddleware'] }`) получать так же данные, а так же через `app.context.sstContext...` - ничего не срабатывает
- на стороне serverMiddleware (`serverMiddleware: ['~/smdw/mymdw']`) получать данные - ничего не срабатывает

Так как же всё можно получить данные запроса в роутер с использованием Nuxt-Link?

Comment: если вам нужно получить какие-то пользовательские данные, можете использовать params или query, nuxt-link это тоже самое что и router-link in Vue.js.
Страница понятное дело не запрашивается с сервера, потому что она уже загружена при первом посещении приложения, получайте данные в точке входа в приложение и во vuex работайте с ними и пробрасывайте куда угодно. Надеюсь помог :)

Comment: @ryzen проблема в том, что это не такие данные, которые нужны стору. это access log. И там должны быть пути, метки времени, размеры и прочая чепуха... всё, что обычно в req,res